# Emergency brake metal latch has snapped off, can it be re-soldered?

Tags: emergency-brakes, soldering

The hammer hook that fixes the emergency-brake has come off and I found that some mechanics [re-solder them](https://youtu.be/iNJOiTm_Gn4?t=274). Can garages also re-solder handbrake cable pieces? Can I have a go myself?

[image]

Comment: That is a really good graphic! :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely that every decent garage will refuse to solder them, because the next defect will be their liability. Instead, they will happily offer to replace the entire cable assembly, including conduit.

Replacing brake cables is an standard job. Repairing them isn't, and likely it is even illegal

Assuming you have an older vehicle: Replacing the entire assembly, inclusive conduit, is advisable. Older cables are often contaminated by water and dirt ingress, resulting in cable wear and rust.

Comment: Agreed. Lots of liability involved. Besides, it would probably cost more in labor costs to try and fix it than it would to just replace it in the first place. You'd still have to completely remove the cable in order to get it fixed (well, most sane people would completely remove it).

Comment: If you were to remove the damaged part and take it to a welding or machine shop, you might be able to get them to weld, braze, or solder it.  At that point it's just some assembly that you brought in.  They don't know what it is and the liability is yours.  But if it were mine, I'd replace it.